# Get current position when changing from position "sticky" to "relative" and set that value to translate

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, getboundingclientrect

I am cloning this website https://www.lifeatspotify.com/ and I am about 90% done, but I am having trouble with the second section "folder flips". I have made the heading stack on each other but when the third heading stacks on top all the links should change to position relative.

I have this code so far:

```
const folderLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".folder-flip-link");

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (folderLinks[folderLinks.length - 1].getBoundingClientRect().top <= 112) {
    folderLinks.forEach((link) => {
      link.style.position = "relative";
    });
  }
});
```

But I don't know how to get the top position like https://www.lifeatspotify.com/

Does anyone have an idea?

Herr is a short video of the problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MoyMbsbAbH5uQYHbxVoOrEcnvAZWXLcx/view?usp=drivesdk